# Listview onClickItem function is not working

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, listitem

I am using `ArrayAdapter` of type `String` with custom layout instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, but when i click on list item then my app crashes.
Here is my logcat.

```
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at com.faisalahsan.healthdroid.DoctorCategoryListActivity$1.onItemClick(DoctorCategoryListActivity.java:55)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:292)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1066)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2522)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3182)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
07-09 20:48:35.549: E/AndroidRuntime(1822):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my activity code.

```
public class DoctorCategoryListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_doctor_category_list);

        String[] doctorCategories =  {"Acupuncturist", "Addiction Specialist"};

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView = getListView();

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapte = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DoctorCategoryListActivity.this, 
        R.layout.layout_doctor_catagory_list_item, R.id.tv_doctor_catagory_list_item, doctorCategories);

                mListView.setAdapter(mAdapte);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {                     
                      // selected item 
                    String speciality = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(DoctorCategoryListActivity.this, speciality+" clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is XML code `layout_doctor_catagory_list_item`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_doctor_catagory_list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="43dp" 
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"        
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: provide code of your DoctorCategoryListActivity

Comment: I would check to make sure you have implemented the correct interface which would be View.OnItemClickListener. The error says you have a cast problem.

Comment: You are performing an invalid cast, most likely you have mixed up the ids of your `Views`: `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_doctor_catagory_list_item);
String speciality = tv.getText().toString();
```

The view that is passed to `onItemClick()` is the **outermost** view of the item's layout (i.e. the `LinearLayout` in `layout_doctor_catagory_list_item.xml`), while the resource id you supplied identifies the `TextView` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

in the onclickitem methode you should do `view.findViewById(Textview)` instead of `((TextView) view).getText().toString();` the view you recieve in the methode onItemClick is the whole Listview Item you passed in the ArrayAdapters Constructor. In your case the whole view is

```
LinearLayout
----TextView
----View(Spacer)
```